# How can I update lists in SML using functions?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, caml, ml

I need to write an SML function that looks like this:

```
update(FLR, (x,y))
```

Where FLR is a finite list of tuples that looks like the following:

```
[(1,1),(2,4),(3,9),(4,16)]
```

But it can contain any number of tuples. What this update function needs to do is take in the list of tuples as the first argument and an x / y tuple as the second argument. If there is a tuple in the list that has the same x value as the one given to the function, it needs to update the y value of the list to the y value given to the function. If there is not a tuple with the x value given, the function needs to create a new tuple in the list at the appropriate location. For example, if the FLR has the values:

```
FLR = [(1,1),(2,4),(3,9),(4,16),(5,25)]
```

and the function is called as `update(FLR, (2,3));` The new list should be `[(1,1),(2,3),(3,9),(4,16),(5,25)]`. Also, if the function is called as `update(FLR, (6,36));` The new list should be `[(1,1),(2,4),(3,9),(4,16),(5,25), (6,36)]`.

I am very new to functional programming and SML and I am not sure how to do this. I have written some memberOf functions that I'm sure I will need to use but my main concern is how to do all of this using recursion. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you written `map` yet? It's pretty similar: you need to walk through the list, working with one element at a time, and producing a new list with elements that correspond 1:1 to elements in the original list.

Comment: That's what I am having trouble with. Could you provide some insight on how to write this function?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't *use* `memberOf`, but you should apply what you learned about lists and recursion while implementing it and similar functions.

That is, how to do case analysis on the structure of a list;

- Do something for the empty list
- For a non-empty list, do something with its head and combine the result with the result of recursing on its tail.

A list transformation function often looks like this:

```
fun transform [] = []
  | transform (x::xs) = (do something with x) :: (transform xs)
```

For instance, a function that replaces every 0 with a given number:

```
fun replace_zero (a, []) = []
  | replace_zero (a, x::xs) = (if x = 0 then a else x) :: (replace_zero (a, xs))
```

That should hopefully get you back on track.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you. I've got it to work for updating an element in the list, but I am unsure of how to add to the list if the element is not found. I can only change the value of an existing element. Here is my function:

Comment: fun update([], (x,y)) = []
  | update((a,b)::ls, (x,y)) =
        (if x = a then (x,y) else (a,b)) :: (update(ls, (x,y)));

Comment: @bobertizkewl If you solve it for the empty list first, I'm sure you will see how to do it.